# Automatic Autodesk OAuth refresh token on expiration

Tags: django-rest-framework, oauth, autodesk-forge

As I'm not sure in which level to solve this issue, I am including all possibilities in this thread.

I am trying to allow users of my application (DRF API) to connect their Autodesk account with their account on my platform. This should match the case B on [this Autodesk article](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/various-uses-autodesk-log). However, in contrast from other providers I've seen, Autodesk refresh token expires after 15 days. If the user doesn't use the system for longer than 15 days and if I don't refresh it somehow automatically, they will have to re-connect their account.

This is basically my question. How should I deal with this issue? I am storing refresh tokens on the database, linked to the user profile. Should I implement a way to automatically refresh the token for the user, so they don't have to re-authenticate? What is the usual approach for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, implementing a way/background service to keep the access token & refresh token fresh automatically on your side is recommended in this scenario.

Here is the API call example:

```bash
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token'
     -X 'POST'
     -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     -H 'Accept: application/json'
     -H 'Authorization: Basic RjZEbjh5cGVtMWo4UDZzVXo4SVgzcG1Tc09BOTlHVVQ6QVNOa3c4S3F6MXQwV1hISw==' \
     -d 'grant_type=refresh_token'
     -d 'refresh_token=GwA1Yc4MOVulVsArZTAz4WxzysDrlEKgfrC06RAyZN'
     -d 'scope=data:read'
```

ref: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/gettoken-POST/#example-3